# Create foreign key relation between tabels in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have to tables like below:

```
class BlogCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Blog category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Blog categories'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Blog(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(BlogCategory, related_name="blogs", null=True, blank=True)
```

I would like to create foregin key relation between Blog and BlogCategory.
Here is my command for postgres:

```
ALTER TABLE blog_blog ADD CONSTRAINT fk_blog_blogcategory FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES blogcategory (name);
```

and i got an error:

```
ERROR:  column "category_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
```

Comment: is there any reason you are not using makemigrations to do this?

Comment: yes, django version 1.0.4

Comment: Okay, then I believe you will also need to create the column category_id on blog_blog before running your original command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this before your original command:

```
ALTER TABLE blog_blog ADD COLUMN category_id integer;
```

Comment: I got ```ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "blog_blogcategory"```

Comment: Try ```ALTER TABLE blog_blog ADD CONSTRAINT fk_blog_blogcategory FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES blogcategory (id);``` instead. Or do you want to use name as the primary key?

Comment: Yes I prefere name. I executed `ALTER TABLE blog_blog ADD COLUMN category_id integer;
ALTER TABLE blog_blog ADD CONSTRAINT fk_blog_blogcategory FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES blogcategory (id);` and I got `ERROR:  relation "blogcategory" does not exist`

Comment: maybe it should be REFERENCES blog_blogcategory (id) instead?

Comment: here is right command: ```ALTER TABLE blog_blog ADD CONSTRAINT fk_blog_blogcategory FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES blog_blogcategory (id);```. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Hah beat me to it! If you want to use name instead, then you will need to add category_name as a column to blog_blog instead (and delete category_id) and make the name field on blog_blogcategory the primary key. Then you should be able to add a foreign key with ```ALTER TABLE blog_blog ADD CONSTRAINT fk_blog_blogcategory FOREIGN KEY (category_name) REFERENCES blog_blogcategory (name);``` Alternatively if you want to leave id as the primary key, you can just add a unique constraint to name.

Answer (score 0):

May be try this :

```
ALTER TABLE blog_blog ADD CONSTRAINT fk_blog_blogcategory FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES blogcategory (name);
```